# Changing the layout of the reopen votes review screen

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, vote-to-reopen

Currently, when reviewing a "reopen vote" the reason why the question was closed (put on hold) is displayed at the bottom of the question.

The information on why a question was closed is important in order to properly evaluate if the question can be reopened. It is quite annoying to scroll all the way down (some questions require quite some scrolling...) to see this important information.

I think it would be better to have the close reason at the top, when reviewing a "reopen vote", something like this:
[image]